# Using XSLT to convert XML in a non-linear way

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I convert the first of the following two XML into the second one, by using XSLT?

The difficulty in doing so is that it's not exactly a linear process, because the first XML groups the comments of a blog by date, whereas the second one group the comments by user.

Input XML:

```
<blog>
    <block>
        <day>2011-11-20</day> 
        <data>
            <comment>bla bla bla</comment>
            <ops>
                <user>357098</user> 
            <ops>
        </data>
    </block>
    <block>
        <day>2011-11-21</day> 
        <data>
            <comment>blu blu blu</comment>
            <ops>
                <user>357098</user> 
            <ops>
        </data>
        <data>
            <comment>bum</comment>
            <ops>
                <user>11111</user> 
            <ops>
        </data>
    </block>
</blog>
```

And I have to get this in output:

```
<blog>
    <user id="357098">
        <list>
            <comment>
                <text>bla bla bla</text>
                <date>2011-11-20</date>
            </comment>
            <comment>
                <text>blu blu blu</text>
                <date>2011-11-21</date>
            </comment>          
        </list>
    </user>
    <user id="11111">
        <list>
            <comment>
                <text>bum</text>
                <date>2011-11-21</date>
            </comment>
        </list>
    </user>
</blog>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical grouping problem and here is an XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kUser" match="data" use="ops/user" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="block/data[generate-id() = 
                                            generate-id(key('kUser', ops/user)[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <user id="{ops/user}">
      <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kUser', ops/user)/comment" />
      </list>
    </user>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment">
    <comment>
      <text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </text>
      <date>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../day" />
      </date>
    </comment>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<blog>
  <user id="357098">
    <list>
      <comment>
        <text>bla bla bla</text>
        <date>2011-11-20</date>
      </comment>
      <comment>
        <text>blu blu blu</text>
        <date>2011-11-21</date>
      </comment>
    </list>
  </user>
  <user id="11111">
    <list>
      <comment>
        <text>bum</text>
        <date>2011-11-21</date>
      </comment>
    </list>
  </user>
</blog>
```